# How to display set of colors, if each color represent a character

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient, android-color

I'm developing an app where each character will represent a specific colour as shown below.[image]

Now, when user type on the keyboard (soft keyboard), I'll display the corresponding colours in the `EditText` (apparently) as shown below.[image]

But it (the colored char) doesn't have to be square only (circle or cube should also be supportable)

Now, the problem is I don't know how to show these coloured sentences in the `EditText`. Should I create a square box, cube or something in `HTML` and then
convert it to formatted `String` or should I have to make `View` list for such purpose? Where each view will represent each character and will display these views in a layout following each other, so it would seem like the second image.
Or should I have to make a dynamic complex gradient image?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a custom view with canvas drawing is most flexible, start here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom font.  Define the characters to be whatever you want to display.  Then set that edit text to that fount.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to make a custom font plz? Also, I forgot to mention that it should be dynamic. Any user will be able to alter the default charset for himself.